# Dashboard.fireChange javaScript error in pentaho Dashboard

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

Without disable the RequireJs, how can I use the Click Action for popup component using `Dashboard.fireChange()` method?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

With require support it’s dashboard (lowercase, singular).

Without require it’s Dashboards (uppercase first letter, plural).

Comment: yes,we can use the first method(dashboard.fireChange('COLOR',color.color);) ,but does not display popup chart(Bar chart:Error Processing Component),what ll u do ??

Comment: You need to open a debugger on your browser and see what exactly is failing in your code. Append &debug=true to the url so that you have the unminified source code to add breakpoints to.